# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceException

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, netbeans-7

I'm new to JavaEE.

I created enterprise application project in NETBEANS 7.2.1 with glassfish server 3.1.

When I try to clean and build I get following error

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or          abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2317)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1899)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.findDeclaredField(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:62)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getField(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:216)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper.getField(Helper.java:934)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.initializeAttributes(InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.java:100)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.preInitialize(DatabaseMapping.java:1284)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.preInitialize(AbstractDirectMapping.java:965)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping.preInitialize(XMLDirectMapping.java:433)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLDescriptor.preInitialize(XMLDescriptor.java:510)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:493)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:476)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:435)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:676)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:634)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.<init>(XMLContext.java:830)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.<init>(XMLContext.java:770)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.<init>(XMLContext.java:177)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.<init>(XMLContext.java:164)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.<init>(XMLContext.java:154)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.objects.PersistenceXMLMappings.createXMLContext(PersistenceXMLMappings.java:123)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.objects.PersistenceUnitReader.initPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUnitReader.java:168)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.objects.PersistenceUnitReader.<init>(PersistenceUnitReader.java:71)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:376)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1153)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:145)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor498.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor498.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor498.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor498.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

This is web.xml file, if it can help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

If more info is needed, please point to it.

By the way earlier it built fine but failed to run with another message. And I didn't change anything in between.

Earlier run fail message:

```
   com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing     resource injection on managed bean shoplist
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:211)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: The runtime classpath is polluted with Java EE API JAR file without method bodies. How exactly did you build the web application? Did you download one or more Java EE related JAR files originating from a completely arbitrary container and placed it in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` in order to "fix" compilation errors on classes from Java EE API?

Comment: You are right. I copied web.xml from earlier attempt to create same project as web application. Is there reason why Netbeans doesn't create web.xml file for enterprise application project? Isn't it necessary?

 Also I had unnecessary file from failed attempt to create remote interface for ejb class, I removed it too. I removed earlier that class with its remote interface, but some file was created automatically which I didn't notice.

Answer (score 8):

Well I had the same problem, I am using netbeans 7.3.1 and when I create a facade database in my class library I was getting the error (using JAva 7 and Glassfish 4)

The problem I was having was when you use the insert code and automatic bean creation it adds the Java EE 6 API library . I deleted the library and add the Java EE 7 API. It worked for me.

Comment: in my case i changed it to `Java EE Web API6`