# NetBeans 8.2 - Weblogic - Ant build

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ant

When I try to build my Enterprise Project in Netbeans with ant, i got this exception:

> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation
>   processor
>   'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor'
>   less than -source '1.8'
>       Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
>
> An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
>       Consult the following stack trace for details.
>       java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file
>   javax/persistence/PersistenceException

I only have some `entity`classes in my ejb module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is reported as a [bug in NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195113) (with a resolved status as it turns out to be considered as a "user error"). Below is the main comment that explains the problem and gives the solution:

> "ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method..." is always indication that javaee-api-6.0.jar is used for runtime execution. **The jar contains only method signatures (method bodies are stripped) and is suitable only for compilation.** In future versions of javac there might be better error message.
>
> **The problem here is that javaee-api-6.0.jar is on classpath before EclipseLink jars and when EclipseLink annotation processor is started classes from javaee-api-6.0.jar are used instead of classes from EclipseLink.** First thing is that javaee-api-6.0.jar should be removed from classpath of EJB project - it should not be needed as EJB project has an Application server selected and the project takes EE 6 APIs from that server.

As I understand the comment, you should try removing any reference to javaee-api-6.0.jar (which contains only "dummy" classes) from the classpath of the project, because the EclipseLink library should provide the correct classes used by the annotation processor.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559336/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-o) seems to tackle the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

when you use the insert code and automatic bean creation it adds the Java EE 6 
   API library . I deleted the library and add the Java EE 7 API.